# Overlay text over bitmap array in C

Tags: c, fonts, bitmap

I am trying to figure out a way to overlay some text over a bitmap array. I would like the text style to be derived from a fixed-size (or padded) font. At the moment, I have a header file with my letter styles, which I then overlay using 'is the bit set? yes? print pixel'.

```
ascii.h:
static char *chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789:.+ ";
static char *ascii =
"        "
"   ##   "
"  ####  "
" ##  ## "
" ###### "
" ##  ## "
" ##  ## "
" ##  ## "
"        "
"        "
" #####  "
" ##  ## "
" ##  ## "
" #####  "
" ##  ## "
" ##  ## "
" #####  "
"        "
"        "
etc...
```

This is then printed like this:

```
#define CHAR_WIDTH  8
#define CHAR_HEIGHT 9

pixel = (ascii[(y * CHAR_WIDTH + x) + (CHAR_WIDTH * CHAR_HEIGHT)] ==  ' ' ? 0x000000 : 0xFFFFFF);
```

This works OK but it looks pretty ugly, especially if I have to scale it. Here's one that's been scaled by 4 times:

[image]

Most of the code examples I've seen to overlay text is around C# or C++ using CImg. I would like to do this using as close to native C as possible.

My options are, as far as I can see them is to either somehow convert a font style text to a load of arrays for each pixel in a letter or find already stylised font array. Basically similar to what I am doing already.

Is there another, simpler, way?

Comment: You could use SDL.  See [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/135168/c-sdl-render-text)

Comment: This seems a bit of an overkill for this.

Comment: The usual approach is to go for a vector or edge-tracing definition for your font, and then draw those edges. Ideally you need to be able to define curved sections. You can then scale your vector data as needed. If you only have a raster or pixel-based font you are very limited in how you can make it look any better when scaled. You can write heuristics that draw diagonal lines round the edges of your raster font, but the results are of limited benefit.

Comment: Interesting - thanks. Probably beyond my skill level to implement this, unless there are some example codes somewhere?

Comment: @GemTaylor how good would doing a bi-linear resizing, of what is essentially a bitmap, look with raster/pixel based font?

Comment: @CaptainJack Whatever you do you will find it difficult to regenerate the inner radius in the letter `B`, for example, and even harder to distinguish between the left straight edge and the right curve, or the diagonal on the bottom of a `2` vs the curve at the top. If you start at a low resolution,  the information just isn't there, and starting at higher resolution you have to "un-DDA" to generate slopes not at 45 degrees. It is simply easier to start with a description that already represents the curves!

Comment: @CaptainJack For a low res font bi-linear will do little more than fill in and knock off the corners, which has some benefit. But with a B, for example, it tends to fill in the middle-right gap. Generally most scaled bitmap fonts tend to look like LED font pretty quickly with simple diagonals, but that still looks better than the un-interpolated scaling.

Comment: If you are tempted to play with shading, you need to ensure that only the edge pixels are shaded, that all inside  pixels are kept sharp, otherwise you just get a blurry mess.

Comment: Ouch - right, I think I better stick with fixed sized fonts. Not a huge deal - it's only for text on a test card. The issue is that the sampling rate at which the test card is generated at varies, which affects horizontal resolution and hence the size of text. Wonder if I'd be better off with simply overlaying an actual bitmap image instead of 'text' and resize that, if needed. Should give better result with bi-linear resizing that individual text items.